# bypass geolocation user confirmation

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<div id="mapholder4"></div>

<script>
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

function showPosition(position)
  {
  var latlon=position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;

  var img_url4="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
  +latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
  document.getElementById("mapholder4").innerHTML="<img src='"+img_url4+"'>";

  }
</script>
```

and I would like to bypass the user confirmation so using html5, I would get the user location without his confirmation. Is it possible to be done?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but either way, DO NOT DO IT.

Comment: `"I would like to bypass the user confirmation"` - Lots of malicious code wants to do that.  Thankfully browsers don't allow it.  In fact, if you do find a way to do this in any given browser, please let us know.  We'd like to report that bug to the browser's maintainer(s).

Comment: "I want to violate the user's privacy. Tell me how I can keep them from noticing". How about "no"

Comment: since you say that, it means that it is possible

Comment: You should look into maxmind geoip, its geoip geolocation done server side

Comment: @David how to report it?

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible in any browser because it would open an obvious security and privacy hole. You should find a work-around by gracefully asking the user for permission.

As we see here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#security

> User agents must not send location information to Web sites without
>   the express permission of the user. User agents must acquire
>   permission through a user interface, unless they have prearranged
>   trust relationships with users, as described below. The user interface
>   must include the host component of the document's URI